# Adwords adgroup mutate service

Tags: google-ads-api

Hi all i'm new to adwords api. im using v201101 version

i'm creating 3 adrgroups to a one campaign at a time using adgroupservice mutate method.

im getting AdGroupReturnValue as return value.

but problem is if one adgroup creation is failed,remaining adgroups are also failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the current version of the AdWords API only supports partial failure for Criterion (keywords/placements etc). Other entity types will either all fail or all commit so you need to validate them first yourself to make sure they won't fail.